# Multiple filter criteria for a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, filter, index-error

Thanks to @James I have a working filter criteria. 
I now tried to create a script that would allow me to upload a datafile which contains a list of stock tickers and issue dates.
Consequently, I want to iterate the list over the filter function.
However, I keep getting

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Any way on how to fix this?
See below the script and function:

Filter function:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import urllib
import datetime

def get_data(issue_date, stock_ticker):
    df = pd.read_csv (r'D:\Project\Data\Short_Interest\mergedshort.csv')
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y%m%d")
    d = df

    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    short = df.loc[df.Symbol.eq(stock_ticker)]
    # get the index of the row of interest
    ix = short[short.Date.eq(issue_date)].index[0]
    # get the item row for that row's index
    iloc_ix = short.index.get_loc(ix)
    # get the +/-1 iloc rows (+2 because that is how slices work), basically +1 and -1 trading days
    short_data = short.iloc[iloc_ix-10: iloc_ix+11]
    return [short_data]
```

and the script to make the iterations and upload the list (which contains a list of 'issue_dates' and 'stock_tickers')

```
import shortdatafilterfinal
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# SHORT DATA trading day time series
# Open File Dialog
# iterates the stock tickers and respective dates over the filter function

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

# Load Spreadsheet data
f = open(file_path)

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
next(csv_f)

result_data = []

# Iterate
for row in csv_f:
    try:
       return_data = shortdatafilterfinal.get_data(row[1], row[0])
       if len(return_data) != 0:
          # print(return_data)
          result_data_loc = [row[1], row[0]]
          result_data_loc.extend(return_data)
          result_data.append(result_data_loc)
    except AttributeError:
          print(row[0])
          print('\n\n')
          print(row[1])
          continue

if result_data is not None:
    with open('resultsshort.csv', mode='w', newline='') as result_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(result_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for result in result_data:
            # print(result)
            csv_writer.writerow(result)
else:
    print("No results found!")
```

Comment: You want +/-1 row from the initial dataframe, or from the result of the first filter?

Comment: I want the +/-1 to be from the result of the first filter, not from the initial dataframe

Comment: @James, I hope it is clear?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want to select +/-1 row from selected date:

```
short = df.loc[df['Symbol'] == 'ARAY']

def get_date(df, d):
    v = short['Date']==d
    return df[v | v.shift(fill_value=False) | v.shift(-1,fill_value=False)]

print(get_date(short, '2011-01-08'))
```

Prints:

```
         Date Symbol
3  2011-01-06   ARAY
6  2011-01-08   ARAY
9  2011-01-12   ARAY
```

Comment: Used the solution provided by James. I went a step further now and ran against an indexerror problem. See edited main post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.iloc` to look around the item index of the filtered results.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Date':['2011-01-03', '2011-01-03', '2011-01-03','2011-01-06', '2011-01-06', 
             '2011-01-06', '2011-01-08', '2011-01-08','2011-01-08', '2011-01-12', 
             '2011-01-12', '2011-01-12'], 
     'Symbol':['ARAY', 'POLA', 'AMRI', 'ARAY', 'POLA', 'AMRI', 'ARAY', 'POLA', 
               'AMRI', 'ARAY', 'POLA', 'AMRI']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def look_around(df, symbol, date):
    short = df.loc[df.Symbol.eq(symbol)]
    # get the index of the row of interest
    ix = short[short.Date.eq(date)].index[0]
    # get the item row for that row's index
    iloc_ix = short.index.get_loc(ix)
    # get the +/-1 iloc rows (you have to use +2 because that is how slices work)
    return short.iloc[iloc_ix-1: iloc_ix+2]

look_around(df, 'ARAY', '2011-01-08')
# returns:
        Date Symbol
3 2011-01-06   ARAY
6 2011-01-08   ARAY
9 2011-01-12   ARAY
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Since I want to turn this into a function that I can use to run a big number of iteration I tried to modify the code slightly, but I have come across a problem. This function should work except for the 'issue_date'. How can you implement the issue_date within the short.query function? I have edited my main post @James

Comment: Added a functionalized version for you.

Comment: I ran against a new problem, trying to put the functionalized version to work. However, receiving indexerrors and no idea on how to fix this.